# why my maps using openstreetmap not rander fully

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, laravel-10

why my maps using openstreets map not rander fully on laravel 10 like this

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
    .openPopup();
```

my expectation fully render my maps[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY3ZY.jpg)